# Add selection to bundle programmatically

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, zend-framework, magento

on import I would like to add imported products as bundled products to a list of bundle products.

I extended Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product and used this class in a custom Dataflow, before the imported row is saved the following code is executed:

```
//Load product model collection filtered by attribute set id        
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', 12);

// loop through products
foreach($products as $p){
    // get product options
    $options = $p->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsCollection($p);
}
```

What I need to do next is determine what is the right option (by title), and add the product as a selection to it.

```
$option->addSelection($selection);
```

But how do I get the option title and how do i create the selection from my product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the option title i did:

```
$option->getData('default_title');
```

To create the selection i did:

```
$selection = new Mage_Bundle_Model_Selection();
$selection->addData(array(
'entity_id' => //bundle id,
'option_id' => $option->getId(),
'product_id' => //bundled item id,
'selection_price_value' => 0.00,
'selection_qty' => 1,
'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
));

$selection->save();
```

to add the selection to the option i did:

```
$option->addSelection($selection);
$option->addData(array(
    'store_id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Abonnement'
));

 $option->save();
```

I don't know why i have to set the title and store_id, because the option already exists so i think it shouldn't be necessary, but if i don't do this i get a "missing store_id" or "missing title" error.

I like Magento but it's huge, documentation should be better.